# ReferenceError: Echo is not defined

Tags: javascript, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I'm using laravel echo with pusher js to build a real-time feature in my app. I've done all the steps required as told by the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting). I've successfully set up the pusher configurations and it works fine: when my event is fired I get it notified in my Debug console on my Pusher account.

My issue is with the front-end. As told by the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo) I've added the portion of code neccessary at the bottom of my `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file. I uncommented it actually and add the proper ids.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key:my-pusher-key-here,
    cluster: eu,
    forceTLS: true
});
```

The issue is that although I've inserted those

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/echo.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
var channel = Echo.channel('my-channel');
channel.listen('my-event', function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
</script>
```

in my blade view, I'm getting this error in the browser's console :`ReferenceError: Echo is not defined`.
I'm guessing it has something to do with echo library not found but I'm not understanding why. For the `<script src="js/echo.js"></script>` line, I copied the echo.js file got after the `npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js` command run.

I went through many suggestions like `gulp` to get the changes in the Js files automatically compiled I guess but nothing... For the `gulp` command entered in my CLI, I'm getting `No gulpfile file found` error. I've also tried to copy the first portion of code directly in the `app.js` file instead but no difference, I'm getting the same error.

As I've said.. I guess this has certainly something to do with the Echo library not found but why that ? Your help will be very appreciated

`package.json` file

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack -p",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "webpack": "^4.39.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.4",
        "pusher-js": "^5.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your JS transpiled or not (webpack/gulp/something else)? If not, I don't think that `import Echo from 'laravel-echo';` syntax will work unless you make it a module: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import (and even so, I recommend webpack)

Comment: @mpen thank you for the answer. sorry for the late reply. I'm totally new with Webpack, I've went through some tutorials on the net but it may be confusing as I'm beginner in I guess... Plus I tried all those : [1](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack/) , [2](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/04/learn-webpack-in-15-minutes) and some YT videos to get the thing. I understand that it's compiling our js assets in one 'bundle' js file. But although with the tuts followed the error persists or i'm getting errors

Comment: For example, with this [tutorial](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/04/learn-webpack-in-15-minutes), the entry point modified to `./resources/js/app.js` in my case, when compiled, I'm getting `ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|<div class="container">
|<div class="row justify-content-center">` error.

Comment: Some assets/modules have been successfully `[built]` but the `ReferenceError : Echo is not defined` is still there

Comment: I may add that : I was having with that sus-mentioned error, another one in the console : `SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module` indexing my `js/echo.js` file.  If this may help help..

Comment: Uhh.. yeah, webpack is kind of a b*tch. It's great once you've learned it, but it can take a few weeks to get a good setup going, even if you're familiar with such things. I haven't used it, but Laravel has a tool called "mix" (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix) which uses webpack under the hood. That might be easier to get started with?
That module parse error probably means you need a loader for `.vue` files (are you using Vue?).  Laravel mix might support vue out of the box, not sure.

Comment: Haha yep. Nope, I'm not using Vue. I'll go with Mix then, go through it.. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 5):

Remove defer from your script tag. This will cause the app.js script to be deferred, and the other script will run first before this script

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `import Echo from 'laravel-echo';` inside `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file.

It tries to search for Echo dependency in **node_modules** folder.

You should use [laravel-mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix) to build JavaScript files.

Comment: thank you for the answer. sorry for the late reply.. I ran `npm run dev` and even `npm run production` [as told](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#running-mix) but the same error persists in the console.. Is there something additional I should do there? I think [this part](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#running-mix) is essentially what laravel mix needs to get files compiled

Comment: @TedAaron can you share your package.json file? Maybe on codepen?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same error as you, the error is happening in your resources/js/app.js file. if you have commented **require('./bootstrap');** uncomment it it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue **Echo is not defined**.

If you're using **Vite instead of Mix** and facing an error after the `npm run dev` command in the front end then you can use this solution.

You can solve this issue by simply adding:

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

instead of:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and set **type="module"** to solve the **ReferenceError: Echo is not defined** error like below:

```
<script type="module">
    var channel = Echo.channel('my-channel');
    channel.listen('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
</script>
```

or, if you don't want to use **type="module"** then you can use

```
window.onload=function(){}
```

like this:

```
<script>
   window.onload=function(){
        var channel = Echo.channel('my-channel');
        channel.listen('my-event', function(data) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
</script>
```

Lastly, run `npm run dev`. No build file will be created. Instead of a build folder, a 'hot' txt file will be created in the 'public' folder to sync with changes. Hopefully, this will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you messed up the steps after uncommenting the lines in `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file. To use the code in there you need to import the `resources/js/app.js` file. Go look in that, you'll see it is importing the bootstrap file. You can import axios in your `resources/js/app.js` as you might need it in your blade.
Confirm that your `resources/js/app.js` file at least has these lines:

```
require('./bootstrap');
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
```

Then in your blade file use this to get vue running:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {},
        methods: {},
        mounted() {},
    });
</script>
```

Finally check the `webpack.mix.js` file and confirm that it at least has:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue();
```

For me, using php 7.4 I had to run `npm run production` to build the js files. And it was running flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Go in terminal,

tape this command : `npm install` and use laravel mix : `npm run dev` that resolve my error.

Thanks.